# Mapping a 2d array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a simple component called GridSquare:

```
import React from 'react';
import './GridSquare.css'

const GridSquare = (props) => {
    
    return (
    <div className="empty-square">
    </div>
    )
}

export default GridSquare;
```

The css file of GridSquare is just making the div a simple gray square:

```
.empty-square{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #555;  
}
```

I'm trying to create a grid of these squares with a component called Grid. I'm having difficulties with mapping the 2d array. Mapping one dimensional array works fine but the 2d array just prints out empty divs.

```
import React from 'react';
import GridSquare from './GridSqure'

const GameGrid= () => {
    const gamegrid=new Array(20);
    for(let i =0; i<gamegrid.length; i++)
        gamegrid[i] = new Array(20);

    console.log(gamegrid);
    
    return(
        <div>
            {
            gamegrid.map((row)=> 
            {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {
                            row.map(() => <GridSquare/>)
                        }
                    </div>
                )})
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default GameGrid;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Array(20)` creates an array of 20 *empty* elements.
The map method ignores *empty* elements, so you should fill your array: `gamegrid[i] = new Array(20).fill(null);`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have it this way:

```
{[...Array(20)].map(() => (
  <div>
    {[...Array(20)].map(() => (
      <GridSquare/>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Instead of defining the dimensions of the grid outside in the `GameGrid` const, you explicitly create an array of `20`, map through it, and create another array of `20` to get your `20X20` grid.

**Note** you can have the `20` as a variable like `let size = 20`, so this part `[...Array(20)]` becomes `[...Array(size)]`
This will give you the ability to dynamically change the grid size of your app

Answer (score 0):

Initializing array that way isn't enough. You should also populate it's elements:

```
for(let i =0; i<gamegrid.length; i++) {
    gamegrid[i] = new Array(20);
    gamegrid[i].fill(1); // this is just an example value
}
```

Also, you should add keys to all the elements you are mapping:

```
return(
    <div>
        {
        gamegrid.map((row, i1)=> 
        {
            return (
                <div key={i1}>
                    {
                        row.map((el, i2) => <GridSquare key={i2} />)
                    }
                </div>
            )})
        }
    </div>
)
```